# mongoose how to populate an array referenced within the model

Tags: mongoose

I am making a blogapp. Two model comment and userProfile, comment looks something like this:

```js
var commentSchema = new Schema({
            userId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'userProfile'},
            replyCommentId: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Comment'}],
            commentDesc: String,
            date: {type: String, default: Date.now()}
          });
```

I have saved replies as comments itself and referenced to main comment via replycomment id stored in array.

I tried to populate those reply fields.

```js
commentsModel.findOne({_id: commentId}).populate('replyCommentId')
.populate('replyCommentId.userProfile').exec(function (err, docs) {
    cb(err, docs);
})
```

I could populate `replyCommentId` with model but `userProfile` within `replycommentId` is not getting populated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it like this:

```js
...

const populateQuery = [];
populateQuery.push({
  path: 'replyCommentId'
}, {
  path: 'replyCommentId',
  populate: {
    path: "userProfile",
    model: "Comment",
  },
});

fields.commentsModel.findById(commentId)
  .populate(populateQuery)
  .exec((error, docs) => {
    cb(error, docs);
  });

....
```

Comment: It worked for me. I got your logic. Thank you. I could give you upvote, but I am new to stack overflow and i am building my reputation.

Comment: Well if you accept my answer you get 2 reputation ;)

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to use two populate quesries to populate replyCommentId and userId inside that. It can be done using one populate.

you can simply try this:

```
commentsModel
    .findOne({_id: commentId}).
    .populate({ 
        path : 'replyCommentId',
        populate : {
            path :'userId'
        }
    }).exec(function (err, docs) {
        cb(err, docs);
    });
```

For more information on Mongoose Populate and its options, please refer to [Mongoose Populate Documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). Look for **Populating across multiple levels**.

Comment: I have tried this, it doesn't work userId is not getting populated with model, it is still being referenced.

Comment: You can try my edited answer. This will work for you